# Значение слова "авось-либо"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика, литература

В "Носе" Гоголя увидел странноватое слово — "авось-либо", встречается аж 2 раза. Что оно значит, почему не написать просто "авось", в чём нюанс? Словари говорят, что это то же, что и "авось", кое-где есть пометка "просторечное" (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE)). Однако по контексту гоголевского произведения кажется, что "авось-либо" означает что-то вроде "ладно бы", "допустим"... Приведу фрагменты из текста.

*Как на беду, ни один извозчик не показывался на улице, и он должен был идти пешком, закутавшись в свой плащ и закрывши платком лицо, показывая вид, как будто у него шла кровь. «Но **авось-либо** мне так представилось: не может быть, чтобы нос пропал сдуру», — подумал он и зашел в кондитерскую нарочно с тем, чтобы посмотреться в зеркало.*

*Он потихоньку приблизился к зеркалу и сначала зажмурил глаза с тою мыслию, что **авось-либо** нос покажется на своем месте; но в ту же минуту отскочил назад, сказавши:
— Экой пасквильный вид!*

"Нацкорпус" вообще выдаёт мне с "авось-либо" только 2 произведения Фонвизина, на их примере яснее не стало (см. [здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE)).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие ещё примеры употребления этого слова встречаются в литературе и — главное — каково его значение, чем оно отличается от обычного "авось"? Возможно, на самом деле значений несколько?..

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309702)).

> *Авось-либо* — просторечная частица, обозначает то же, что разговорное *авось*. Различия только стилистические.

Comment: Ну и как, вы довольны ответом Грамоты.ру, ожидали чего-то большего?  Вот раньше (по Далю) к слову могли относиться ещ 5 частиц, а что они означали? В частности, частица ЛИБО наиболее частотная и интересная. В чем было ее дополнительное значение? У Грамоты нужно конкретно спрашивать. Правда, есть вероятность,что тогда она "конкретно" не ответит. Спросите у нее про боевое знамя, можно прямо по ссылке. А то здесь всё очень неясно с выбором прописной или строчной буквы.

Comment: О боевом знамени (Справка не обращает внимания на строчную букву): Вопрос № 294357 Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно употребляется фраза "боевое знамя воинской части внесли или вынесли на плац или на сцену клуба". Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Оба варианта верны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве возможной версии

1. ***Авось либо/авось-либо.***

Если исходить из семантики этих двух слов, то «либо» придавало слову «авось» дополнительное значение надежды на лучшее  **в текущих ситуациях с двумя** определенными и заранее известными исходами: ***либо это, либо то.***

*Авось-либо нос пропал сдуру и теперь покажется на своем месте. Авось либо Бульба, проснувшись, раздумает ехать сразу и отсрочит денька на два отъезд.*

2. В дальнейшем  значение слова авось" **было расширено** до желания положительного результата **среди многих возможных,** когда выбор не ограничивался только двумя уж известными, а был неопределенным, в том числе во времени. И тогда частица «либо» утратила свое значение.

*Авось забудут или же дело сделается как-то само собой. Пусть живёт, авось не объест. Ключи он оставил в замке ― авось какой-нибудь криминальный элемент возьмет да и угонит.*

3. В настоящее время "авось" — это не только **частица,** но и **существительное** мужского рода.

**АВОСЬ.**

I. частица. Разг. Может быть, вдруг, случайно (о том, на что говорящий надеется, считает возможным). Буду ждать, а. придёте. Пойду в парк, а. погода наладится. А. Бог поможет.

II. неизм. м. **Случайная удача, везение.** * На авось вся надежда наша (Посл.). Авось да небось до добра не доведут (Посл.). Да понадеялся на русский авось (Пушкин). Авосю верь не вовсе (Посл.).

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что до первой четверти двадцатого века частица писалась чаще без дефиса (*авось либо*), поэтому вам поиском в Нацкорпусе и не удалось найти достаточно примеров.
Вот здесь их поболе: [авось либо](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=3&req=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE&sort=i_grstd&text=lexform).

> Рыдая, глядела она им в очи, когда всемогущий сон начинал уже смыкать их, и думала: "**Авось либо** Бульба, проснувшись, отсрочит денька на два отъезд; может быть, он задумал оттого так скоро ехать, что много выпил".
> [Н. В. Гоголь. Тарас Бульба](https://books.google.ee/books?id=8C5Q0p-1y0kC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%20%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C,%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4;%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB.&source=bl&ots=levuWhI71C&sig=ACfU3U1Jp7FajmcGdh7i5_S0IuSgIheRwA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_oNLvqrf4AhXli8MKHR42Bd8Q6AF6BAgZEAM#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%20%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%3B%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB.&f=false)

Я хотел вступиться за права законного наследника, но она меня умоляла не трогать Зосю, **авось либо** само все придет к лучшему концу. [Т. Г. Шевченко. Близнецы (1855)]

*"...И похитишь ли их где, или купишь,

Привези их к Скадру на Бояну —

Заложить под башню в основанье:

**Авось либо** будет оно твердо,

**Авось либо** выстроим мы город!"*
А. Х. Востоков. Строение Скадра (1826)

У Даля:
авось — наречие (а-во-се, а вот, сейчас; см. *во*) иногда с придачею частиц: ко, то, же, ну, вот, **либо**; может быть, станется, сбудется, с выражением желания или надежды (латинское *fore ut*).

В словаре устаревших слов:
[авось-либо](https://deti-online.com/slovar-ustarevshih-slov/) — возможно, может быть.

Интересная, как мне кажется, информация о загадочном слове "авось" есть вот в этой статье: [*Откуда произошли слова «авось» и «авоська»? Тайна буквы «А»*](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/gramotnost/otkuda-proizoshli-slova-avos-i-avoska-taina-bukvy-a-6002e66efd62ee0689007bd1).